# How to fix "CreateDirectory: Relative paths not supported" when using a variable?

Tags: nsis

As a newbiew, I am still in the stage of experimenting and building little prototypes. The idea is to build a silent installer that has all settings in multiple sections of a .INI and the users calls the setup with parameter `/config={NameOfSection}`.
My current situation:

#### FooBar-install.ini

```
[PROD]
FOOHOME=c:\FooBar
```

#### FooBar.nsi

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!insertmacro GetParameters
!insertmacro GetOptions 

var /GLOBAL config
var /GLOBAL cmdLineParams
var /global REGAPPKEY
var /global FOOHOME

!define TheName "FooBar"
!define OutFileSuffix "-Install."
!define IniFile "$EXEDIR\${TheName}${OutFileSuffix}ini"

Name "${TheName} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"     ; bei 2 Kunden geht's auch kd-spezifisch ;)
OutFile ${TheName}${OutFileSuffix}exe

RequestExecutionLevel admin
Icon "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-install.ico"
UninstallIcon "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-uninstall.ico"


Section "-aInstaller Section"


ReadINIStr $FOOHOME ${IniFile} $config "FOOHOME"
MessageBox MB_OK "ini=${IniFile} , config=$config, FOOHOME=$FOOHOME"
CreateDirectory "SFOOHOME"


SectionEnd


function .onInit
UserInfo::GetAccountType
pop $0
${If} $0 != "admin" ;Require admin rights on NT4+
    MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
    SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
${Else}    
MessageBox  MB_OK "onInit"
${EndIf}
    ; Get parameters
${GetParameters} $cmdLineParams

    ; /? param (help)
ClearErrors

${GetOptions} $cmdLineParams '/?' $R0

IfErrors +3 0
MessageBox MB_OK "Befehlszeilenparameter /config={{name}} verweist auf einen Abschnitt aus ${TheName}${OutFileSuffix}ini mit div. Parametern zur Steuerung des Setup"
Abort


Call parseParameters
Pop $R0






FunctionEnd


Function parseParameters
    ; /config
${GetOptions} $cmdLineParams '/config=' $R0
${If} ${Errors}
StrCpy $config "errPROD"
${Else}
StrCpy $config $R0 
${Endif}
FunctionEnd
```

#### Problem

If I try to compile this, I get the msg

```
CreateDirectory: Relative paths not supported
Usage: CreateDirectory directory_name
```

#### Questions

1. I do not understand why this error comes up at compile time. When using a variable (especially in this situation where the variable depends on user-input), it does not seem to make sense to complain about the argument when it is not known.
2. How can I avoid this probolem?
3. A little puzzle that messes me up is the syntax to refer to variables.The statement `MessageBox MB_OK "ini=${IniFile} , config=$config, FOOHOME=$FOOHOME"` shows that. I found that I needed to enclose IniFile in {} in order to display its value (I commented out the CreateDir-line to compile the installer and check my assumptions). When do I have to use `{}`?
4. If you see any other "unusual" things in my little script, I'd be happy to know ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, change `CreateDirectory "SFOOHOME"`  to `CreateDirectory "$FOOHOME"`

You might want to read the documentation again to learn the basics; `${define}`, `$(langstring)` and `$variable`.